# How can i create Google Maps link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi Guys i want make a link and this link include latitude and longitude in javascript function can you help me about this.

My javascipt code:

```
function jsFilter(item) {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
                    item.Agency.forEach(agency=> {
                        $("#myDiv").append(
                            "<div style='border-style:ridge;'>Agency Name : <strong>" + agency.name+ "</strong><br>" +
                            "Agency Adress : <strong>" + agency.ADRESS_TEXT + "</strong><br>" +                            
                            "Agency EMail: <strong>" + agency.EMAIL+ "</strong></div>",
                            "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + agency.lat+ ',' + agency.lon   // i wanna add here.
                        );
                    });
                }
```

Comment: please tell us what is working, and what is not working. what do you need?

Comment: `"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + agency.lat+ ',' + agency.lon` this line seems like a text but i wanna make a link in here thats it sir.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the most of your code looks good, i guees you only needed the correct maps link and how the values are applyed to it?

Then thats what you need:

```
function jsFilter(item) {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
                    item.Agency.forEach(agency=> {
                        $("#myDiv").append(
                            "<div style='border-style:ridge;'>Agency Name : <strong>" + agency.name+ "</strong><br>" +
                            "Agency Adress : <strong>" + agency.ADRESS_TEXT + "</strong><br>" +                            
                            "Agency EMail: <strong>" + agency.EMAIL+ "</strong></div>" +
                            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/@" + agency.lat + "," + agency.lon + "\">Google Maps Link</a>"
                        );
                    });
                }
```

*// EDIT*
Added the Link as HTML link.

### Edit 2

As of the discussion in the comments, you needed a syntax for a HTML Link.
Solution:

```
// replace this line:
"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + agency.lat+ ',' + agency.lon"
// with:
"<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + agency.lat+ "," + agency.lon+ "\">google link</div>"
```

This will give you an working Google Maps link.

Comment: i get this error with @ : Parser Error Message: "" + agency.lat+ ',' + agency.lon+ "" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.  and without @ it is not seem on my page. just write Google Maps Link

Comment: yes sir i think problem is @ cause this give me red. and delete @ it is not seem just write google maps link.

Comment: i have tested it and it is working. What is the context? Where are you using this code? Are you using it in any other programming language? Are you inserting this JS Code from anywhere else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193983/discussion-between-sunchezz-and-mustafa).

Comment: no everything looks fine but @ is give me error as i say and i delete i it is not give me a error but not seem like a link with your code.